# increment/decrement click component. How to save data to db.json?

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, json-server

I got a react functional component that can increment or decrement a number.
When the page is loaded, i want this number to be read in the db.json file from my JSON-SERVER and displayed in my view. I also want to update the number in the db.json file when i increment or decrement the value in my page.

I tried to console.log the data coming from the db.json, and what i see is that console.log is displayed 2 times in my console :

- first time an empty []
- second time it is good [{"clicks":20,"id":1},{"clicks":50,"id":2}]

What i tried so far was to display the clicks value with { clicked[0].clicks }
but the '.clicks' leads me to an undefined error...

What am i doing wrong ? Thanks for your help!

```
const CountClick = (props) => {
    const componentTitle = 'Count Click Component';
    const [clicked, setClicked] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await axios(
                'http://localhost:4000/clicked'
            );  
        setClicked(result.data);
        };
        fetchData(); 
    },[]);

    console.log('clicked array', JSON.stringify(clicked));

    return (          
            <div>
                <span className="result">Counter value: { clicked.clicks }</span> 
                <button onClick={ () => {setClicked(clicked.clicks + 1);saveClicks(clicked.clicks + 1)} }>+1</button>
                <button onClick={ () => {setClicked(clicked.clicks - 1);saveClicks(clicked.clicks - 1)} }>+1</button>
            </div>
    );
```

I except to display the "clicks" value in my view

Comment: The question is unclear... what is `saveClicks`? Also are you asking how to `post` (add to the db) or is the data already there and you're trying to `get` from the db and display?

Comment: hello, the saveClicks is a function to save the number into my db.json, but i removed if from the code tobe more consice, as i'm already stuck when i want to display what comes from the db.json

Comment: The code is not really clean but assuming that it's successfully adding to the db... what you are missing is `axios.get`

Comment: axios.get is replaced by the async call, so the problem comes when i call clicked[0].clicks to get my data i have an undefined error in react.

Comment: Why do you have 2 objects? What does this represent? I thought that you were just increasing and decreasing the counter on one number. If you do need multiple objects, try adding a null check like `Counter value: { clicked[0] ? clicked[0].clicks : 0 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming save and load functions work correctly is a simple check for the display, you can use sth like lodash isEmpty or check length of the array if more than 1 item display count.

IsEmpty(Clicked) ? Loading : clicked[0].clicks

UseEffect works in a similar pattern to component did mount. The data is loaded after the component renders to screen so at the time your clicked value is empty and no clicks can be displayed aka undefined